# Issue transcoding video file

Tags: java, javafx

I need to build a JavaFx desktop app which compresses/transcodes a large video file (+2.5gb).

I'm looking into the IVCompressor framework, but it throws an error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

```
        String pathToSrc = "/Users/tm/Desktop/source.mp4";
        String pathToDst = "/Users/tm/Desktop/target.mp4";

        IVCompressor compressor = new IVCompressor();
        IVSize customRes = new IVSize();
        customRes.setWidth(400);
        customRes.setHeight(300);
        File file = new File(pathToSrc);
        compressor.reduceVideoSizeAndSaveToAPath(file, VideoFormats.MP4, ResizeResolution.R480P,pathToDst);
```

Maybe this isn't the right framework for the job. Is there a native library which can be embeded in a JavaFx app for Windows and Os X?

Comment: Serious question: why would you do this in java at all? Using a tool like ffmpeg to do your transcoding is going to be so much faster, and is a known quantity in terms of how to invoke it to do literally anything to video streams you need. Is there a specific reason you're doing this in Java rather than having Java trigger an ffmpeg pass on your file and waiting for that process to compelete?

Comment: Absolutely agree. I can understand why you might try to simplify things though so yes, use ffmpeg as your back end and make it simple at the front end